# RDLC : No page break - four sub reports within table/tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, rdlc, rdl

I have a situation where i have to display four reports based on checkboxes. So user can select different combination from four reports.

My problem is page breaks. I have tried different options (see below) from which two options (option 1 and 2) does not give page breaks at all whether option 3 gives page breaks for each tablix regardless of you do not want to see that report. Report is giving empty page for each tablix no matter there is no data in that tablix to be displayed.

With option 3 if i select all reports to show then everything is perfect.

I have tried these options

## Option 1   (page break does not work)

Main Tablix -> each row : all subreports within rectangle within each row of tablix

## option 2   (page break does not work)

Main Tablix -> each row -> Another tablix with group by ID within each row of tablix and then subreport inside each tablix. And I applied page break end on each tablix.

## option 3   (page break works but gives empty page for non selected reports)

A List group by ID -> within a single row of this list I have places four tablix group by ID for each subreport.

Option 3 works but gives empty page break for those reports which are not selected. For example from Four reports if you select last two reports to display then you will get two empty pages in the beginning of report and third report on third and fourth report on fourth page which is correct. I have tried hiding tablix using table hidden and group properties hidden but still getting page breaks.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue. For those who are struggling with same kind of situation, here is my work around.

I placed one list box and then four tables in a row and i placed subreports within these tables. i didn't apply any page break here. I am only showing and hiding tables based on report selection here.

Trick is within subreports. 
As there were lots of tables and groupings in each report so i placed one table at the end of the each subreport.

This table should only have one cell. I removed header and 2 extra columns which were not required. Select dataset for this table. I did not want to pass dummy empty dataset so I selected my dataset but I created grouping on a parameter which I was passing from parent report and it has value 1. So now this table will only display 1 empty row. Reduce the height of the table. Plus I removed the border of textbox inside the cell. I checked 'Page break at end' option. In the Hidden expression I used following code which checks if there is any report which is visible after this (current) report. If yes then do not hide this table mean you want page break otherwise hide it mean no page break.

```
=iif(Parameters!AddReport_2.Value,false
,iif(Parameters!AddReport_3.Value,false
,iif(Parameters!AddReport_4.Value,false
,true)))
```

This solution works for me.

I would love to hear for a better solution.